# How can I boost up OpenCV performance on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es, opencv, convolution

I'm using AVFoundation to capture video along with OpenCV to do image processing on iPhone. However, I'm considering using OpenGL shaders to do calculations (convolving) on 192x144 grayscale image.

My question is: does it make sense to use OpenGL, I mean: isn't rendering into IplImage (is it even possible?) too slow? Or, is there a way which will speed-up the convolving?

**EDIT**

In OpenCV, I'm using

```
IplConvKernel* kernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(3, 3, 1, 1, CV_SHAPE_CROSS, NULL);
```

with `cvMorphologyEx`.

Comment: If your convolution kernel is symmetric, then you can implement the separable version (rows-then-columns), which involves far less computations than the naive version. Back in the days of Pentium 3 mobile, I could make realtime convolutions on bigger images with this algorithm (small kernel support).Maybe you could precise what kind of convolution you're doing ?

Comment: @sansuiso I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 7):

Even with the use of NEON vector operations via something like the Accelerate framework (which OpenCV currently doesn't use, if I'm not missing something), it's going to be hard to beat the performance of shaders when running simple 3x3 convolution kernels. For example, I can run a Sobel edge detection kernel on a 640x480 frame of video in 2.5 ms on an iPhone 4 using shaders, which is more than fast enough for realtime image processing. Also, OpenGL ES shaders have significant advantages when processing for display, because you can keep everything on the GPU side the whole way through and avoid expensive data transfers for the drawing events.

If you want a simple way to so this, my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework has some very fast built-in convolutions, like Sobel edge detection or an image sharpening kernel, and it lets you create your own 3x3 convolution kernels pretty easily. It wraps all of the OpenGL ES for you, so you don't need to know anything about that (unless you want to write your own custom effects, but even there you just need to know a little GLSL).

For example, to do only the X component of the Sobel edge detection kernel, you can set up your convolution filter with the following code:

```
GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter *filter = [[GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter alloc] init];
[filter setConvolutionKernel:(GPUMatrix3x3){
    {-1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f},
    {-2.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f},
    {-1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}
 }];
```

You then just have to attach this to a camera, image, or movie input and display, raw data, or movie recorder output and the framework will handle the rest. For best performance, you might choose to write your own custom implementation that is optimized to the particular kernel you want to run, like I've done for the GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've forget to mention that in OpenCV I'm mostly convolving **grayscale** 16x16 ROI. I've tried your framework, but it seems, that it assumes the image to be RGB (am I wrong?). Question: isn't copying memory from CPU to GPU (and back) consuming (I have no idea)?

Comment: @user961912 - You can use color or grayscale images. If you look at my Sobel filter, I actually convert the image to grayscale via a luminance filter first and then perform the filtering on the red channel of that. You could cut out the grayscale conversion if your source image is already greyscale.

Comment: @user961912 -  As for your question, if you look at the way the framework operates, on iOS 5.0 it routes data to OpenGL ES from AV Foundation directly, which is extremely fast. If you wish to save image data out, I provide direct access to the OpenGL ES textures on iOS 5.0, which is also fast. My iOS 4.0 fallbacks use slightly slower code, but even then the upload / download times don't slow the whole process down enough to bring it into the same ballpark as on-CPU processing.

Comment: I've realized I'm already using OpenGL ES for rendering (game). As I've been looking at the GPUImage's source, it also (suprisingly) initializes OpenGL. So, is it meaningful (and efficient) to rewrite the source and to change OpenGL's programs (I mean with `glUseProgam()`) every frame (firstly to render a scene, secondly to convolve the image)?

Comment: @user961912 - I don't know what you mean by "it also (suprisingly) initializes OpenGL". I do set up a shared OpenGL ES context within the framework for performing the rendering, but how else would I perform the rendering I describe? If you wish to filter the results of your game's rendering, you will want to render your game scene to a texture-backed FBO. From there, you can do another pass with your own custom shader, or you could feed that texture into GPUImage and let it do this. See my CubeExample within the framework for how you can do postprocessing like this on an OpenGL ES scene.

Comment: I'm rendering the game and in background and I'm simultaneously capturing video by AVFoundation and trying to convolve it, but I don't know any other way to perform both actions on GPU, than by changing shaders (one for the game, other for the convolving) by `glUseProgram()`. P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @user961912 - Don't worry, I understand most of what you are asking, so you're expressing yourself clearly enough. I just wasn't sure about that one phrase in your comment. Again, take a look at my CubeExample sample, which shows how to capture camera video, filter it, give that to a 3-D OpenGL ES scene, use it as a texture, and then take that entire scene and filter that. It sounds like the first part of this example is what you want to do here, so you should be able to build on that.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me :). I want **just** to process the captured image (i.e. I don't want it to be rendered in OpenGL). I thought it could be done with threads, but since it couldn't be the best idea (deadlocks etc. (...yes, I know about NSOperation)), now I don't know which is better - to convolve the 16x16 image by OpenGL or with optimized NEON+ASM code.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any relevant material on this, so I guess it's impossible to say for sure if a implementation using shaders of this algorithm would have better performance with small images like 192x144.

Since this is not a complex implementation, if you have the time I encourage you to do it and measure the performance gain of both implementations.

Please report back to us with your findings if you decide to follow this path.